# Microsoft cognitive services Face API

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services, face-api

What is suggested (optimal) image size to work with face API. Can't find anything about this.

Looks like images should not be to small but either too large. Probably any recommendation how to prepare them before train model?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This may help from the "Add Face" [documentation](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f30395250):

> JPEG, PNG, GIF (the first frame), and BMP format are supported. The allowed image file size is from 1KB to 4MB.
>
> "targetFace" rectangle should contain one face. Zero or multiple faces will be regarded as an error. If the provided "targetFace" rectangle is not returned from Face - Detect, there’s no guarantee to detect and add the face successfully.
>
> Out of detectable face size (36x36 - 4096x4096 pixels), large head-pose, or large occlusions will cause failures.
> Adding/deleting faces to/from a same face list are processed sequentially and to/from different face lists are in parallel.